# Check if user already has an account just by email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I check if a user exists in my Firebase Database only by email within Swift?

The first screen the user should see allows him to type in his email. After that he gets to the sign up page or the login page depending on wether or not the user exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail:completion:), which returns the sign-in methods with which the given email is registered. With that information you can build a sign-in screen.

Comment: and if the user is not registered, the function returns nil?

Comment: @Chris The function has two parameters that are populated in the completion block `method, error`. Method (a SignInMethodQueryCallback) will be the sign in method used for that email account and error will be an error in the call. The 'method' var is what you want and will be nil if the email address does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: email) { (providers, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print(providers)
            }
        }
```

If the email address has not yet been used, the empty list (`providers`) will be printed.

Comment: I think this is the same answer as Frank suggested. Probably best not to duplicate answers if possible. Also, the empty list will not be printed as the providers parameter will be nil, so `nil` will appear in the console. That may be what you meant.